# How much memory is allocated for each element when you dimension an array?

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, memory-management

For instance, in VB.NET:

```
  Dim strArray(5) As String
```

As I understand it, because this is an array, the computer will allocate contiguous memory locations for each of the 5 elements.  But how much space is allocated for each of the five elements?  What if I decide to put a 5MB block of text in position 2 of the array?

Is it different for value types (e.g., an array of Int32)?  I would think if it had to resize the block of memory for an individual element it would have to create a whole new array to preserve the contiguous memory feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET:

- Arrays are usually stored on the heap (unless you use something like `stackalloc` in C#)
- If you create an array of reference type values (e.g. strings) the array *only* contains the references
- A reference is 4 bytes when running the 32-bit CLR, and 8 bytes when running the 64-bit CLR
- Although the array itself is contiguous in memory, there's nothing to say that the strings themselves will be contiguous

So in your case, the array object itself will be

```
normal object overhead 
+ 4 bytes for the length (IIRC) 
+ (4 or 8 bytes per element) * 6 elements
```

The references within the array may refer to any string anywhere in memory, or `Nothing`.

For value types, the array holds the value directly - so an array of `Int32`s will take up:

```
normal object overhead
+ 4 bytes for the length
+ 4 bytes per element
```

An array of `Int64`s will take:

```
normal object overhead
+ 4 bytes for the length
+ 8 bytes per element
```

(etc). Booleans take up a byte per element, despite logically only being a single bit.

Answer (score 4):

If you make an array of a reference type, I think only the *references* are kept in the variable. That is:

```
Dim strArray(5) As String
```

Will only actually be 6 *references* big with something like 4 bytes per reference (not sure on that).

The actual data will be stored (probably) on the heap.

This doesn't mean that changing a string's length is trivial, though--they must still be reallocated each time they are changed.

Comment: It seems to be 6 as the array is zero indexed

Comment: Nope, it's 6--in VB, you declare the *upper bound*, not the count." And it's always zero-based.

Comment: Right. I never liked how VB has you declare the upper bound.